# Why was my closure flag declined for this question?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, vote-to-close

I flagged [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/74650/matlab-code-for-multhopp-lifting-line-methods) question as off topic several days ago.  I did, and still do, think that it is not a good fit for this site.  As of today, five days after being posted, it has yet to receive an answer.  The question is essentially asking for someone to provide a tutorial on how to do a calculation.  How is this question not off topic on this site?

Comment: these users thought differently: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/close/49289 I cannot tell you why, though

Comment: there's another pending review https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/close/49400 w/ 3x close

Comment: @Federico because JZYL linked to an appropriate answer. A majority of qualified users reckoned that the question and answer are  relevant to this Aviation site, since it is a question on methodology for computing lift and drag of a wing.

Comment: @Koyovis but the question linked by JZYL is better by a mile, imho. the one under discussion here: 1. does not provide the "non working" code nor formulas, so we can't check what has been done 2. asks for "help or recommendations" and that's too broad for an SE site. I would have voted to close as unclear/too broad/needs more detail, but I first looked at it when I saw this meta question

Answer (score 2):

Someone flagged/voted a [second time](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/close/49400), and it's now been closed.

---

Frankly, "gimme code" is even *closable* for the programming sites on SE, let alone here, which doesn't provide code help.

An instance in the past is not indicative of what is on-topic, there's a lock reason for this particular issue. And not every question goes.

SE is focused, for a good reason, and the questions need to be on-topic and focused.